# Cannot use state monad in IO context

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I am trying to use the State monad to do some computations while also altering it. I have implemented the instances of `Applicative`, `Monad` and `Functor` as well as `get` and `put` ,`modify`, etc.
I do not understand the desugaring of the `do` block. How do you supply both the state and the state transformer?

**Utils**

```
    get::State s s
    get=State $ \s ->(s,s) 

    put::s->State s ()
    put x=State $ \_ -> ((),x)

    modify::(s->s)->State s ()
    modify f=get>>= \x -> put (f x)

    evalState::State s a->s->a
    evalState act =fst . run act

    execState::State s a->s->s
    execState act=snd.run act
```

**Code**

```
module Env where
    import State 
    import System.Directory
    import Control.Monad
    data Env=Env{
        envName::String,
        fileNames::[String]
    }
    instance Show Env where 
        show Env{envName=x,fileNames=xs} = "{ envName:"++x++" , files: ["++foldr (\t y-> t++","++y) "" xs ++"] }"

    initEnv::IO Env
    initEnv=do
        name<- getLine
        names<- getCurrentDirectory>>=listDirectory
        return Env{envName=name,fileNames=names}

    changeName::String->State Env ()
    changeName (y:ys)=State $ \ (Env (x:xs) ls) -> ((),Env (y:xs) ls)

    toStats::State Env String
    toStats= State $ \env -> (show env,env)

    useEnv::IO (State Env String)
    useEnv=do
        liftM put initEnv   --passes state transformer
        liftM changeName getLine  --passes strate transformer
        print . evalState . toStats         --how do i supply both ?
        return toStats
```

As you can see, in my last line I am initializing the state transformer and passing it for further altering... until i reach `evalState` and I want to use it. In this case i do not know how to supply the state and the transformer.

**P.S** By transformer i mean the wrapper over the `s->(a,s)`

Comment: You aren't actually using a transformer here. Compare your `State` type with [`StateT` from transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT).

Comment: Not too important, but some notes on code formatting: 1) Most Haskellers put spaces around `::` and `=`, and 2) You don't need to indent after the first `module` line

Comment: to disambiguate, you could always use "state-transforming function" instead of "state transformer", so there's no possibility of confusing it as being about monad transformers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't use any monad transformers. I think you're just looking for

```
useEnv :: IO ()
useEnv = do
    env <- initEnv
    name <- getLine
    let actions = do
            changeName name
            toStats
    let str = evalState actions env
    putStrLn str
```

i.e. run the `State` actions from inside an `IO` do block.

Comment: @ OP: here `actions` is not an `IO` "action" value representing an I/O computation. being bound via `let`, as far as the IO `do` block is concerned it is a "pure" value, a State Monad "action", a *state--transforming* pure function wrapped inside a State Monad type. then `evalState actions` *treats* it as a State Monad action and *runs* it by supplying it with the initial state, the pure value `env`. `initEnv :: IO Env` so it follows `env :: Env` (since it is bound with the `<-` construct, not `let`). This means `actions :: State Env String`. it is also the type of `toStats`, so, all is OK.

Comment: (contd.) so, the direct answer to your question "How do you supply both the state and the state transformer?" is, *by using `evalState`* as shown in this answer.

Comment: Yes i couldn't picture how do you couple together forming the initial state and then supplying it to the state monad.In @melpomene 's example i understood that you can define a group of actions that use the state **BEFORE** you actually call the `evalState` with the initial state.